# Is there a .NET port of Drupal?

Tags: .net, drupal

Is there a .NET port of Drupal?

I love Drupal... I love the idea. I want it to be .NET because we are a Microsoft shop and have resources to create .NET components.

Comment: Jason, I love Drupal, and I love .NET. However, I do not at all like PHP. We have actually been looking at initiating a project to develop a Drupal-like system for .NET but have not been able to ascertain whether there would be any interest. This project is of great interest to us.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is 'No.' Drupal is based on PHP, which is a significantly different animal from .NET. A Drupal 'port' would actually be a complete rewrite for .NET.

Perhaps with the advent of .NET MVC, some progress might be made. An alternative to consider might be [the MVC-based Oxite.](http://visitmix.com/Lab/Oxite)

Comment: Thanks... looks really cool, but I need a fully compatible Drupal solution. One day... ;)

Comment: Can you define "fully compatible"? You'll never be able to drop a Drupal module into an .NET version of it without major conversions going on.

Comment: Well... that would be ideal, no? That is pretty much what I'm looking for.

Comment: Yeah, you can forget compatible. The good thing about Drupal is that you can write modules / plugins that both hook into the Drupal API, as well as do whatever else you want. There's too much custom PHP code involved. If every function relied on the Drupal API, it might be more easily portable.

If you're that desperate, perhaps consider doing a mix/match. PHP isn't too hard to get up and going on IIS.

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked into [Drupal.net](http://sourceforge.net/projects/drupal-net/)?

Comment: Drupal.net is not maintained. This was a project that was basically started and abandoned. It's still back on Drupal 6, and the Drupal is in process of finalizing 8.

Comment: Good for ideas anyway.  It's the only port to .NET I know of.

Comment: Drupal is in the process of finalizing version 7. Drupal 8 is still a twinkle in Dries' eye.

Comment: Sorry -- my bad for lack of clarity. I was reading Dries' post '8 steps for Drupal 8' and it seemed like the concept was very close to being finalized. http://buytaert.net/8-steps-for-drupal-8

Comment: You could probably run Drupal under Phalanger. However, a direct port is likely of no value.

Answer (score 2):

Clarifications on those answers.

Drupal 6 is the current version. Version 7 is entering code freeze in the next few weeks, but D6 will still be used to develop sites for at least another 12 months. It's yet to be determined what sort of animal D8 will actually be at this stage.

Drupal isn't based on the MVC architectural pattern, but is much more like the PAC architecture - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presentation-abstraction-control - with hooks and events.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I was mistaken from Dries' latest blog post.

Answer (score 0):

The first step in selecting any software system is choosing the technology you want to work with. If PHP is a no-go, then Drupal is too.

Of course, that does not mean you can't find ways to communicate with Drupal or insert content using .NET. The [Services](http://drupal.org/project/services) module and xmlrpc are both mechanisms by which a .NET application could interact with Drupal.